# How to set value of form field if that view is included in two calling tabs?

Tags: extjs

I am using a view which has some fields like:

```
items: [
        {
            xtype:'textareafield',
            name: 'name_content'

        }]
```

Now this view has been included in other multiple views(Multiple tabs).

I am setting the value in the field by using getForm().findField('name_content).setValue().

It is working if one tab call the view.But If two tabs are opened both calling the same view. Value is not being displayed for send one.

How should I do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try assigning an id to the text area and then using Ext.getCmp('id').
I've seen some ExtJS people say that there are better/more efficient ways than using "id" but you can at least make sure that works.

```
items: [
    {
        xtype:'textareafield',
        name: 'name_content',
        id: 'my_text_area_id',

    }]
```

Then later

```
Ext.getCmp('my_text_area_id').getValue();
```